# Regex - select but not

Tags: .net, regex, c#-4.0

I am new to regular expression and want to create two regexes for my .net application.

I have an input variable which stores an xml. Below is the xml

```
<Row>
......
</Row>
<Row {optional}>
.... 
</Row>
<Row {optional} header="true" {optional}>
</Row>
```

I want 2 regexes: 
1. Regex which selects Rows with header="true"
2. Regex which selects Rows which do not have header="true"

Regex only have to consider opening tag. eg:

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not the best option for processing xml in .NET
If your're using .NET 3.5 or higher, check out [LINQ to xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693072.aspx)
For an older version of the runtime see [XmlDocument and XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx(v=vs.110).aspx)

Using LINQ your code would be something like this:

```
    var document = XDocument.Load("path to your file"); // or XDocument.Parse if you have content in a string
    var elementsWithHeaders = document.Descendants("Row").Where(x => 
         x.Attribute("header")!=null && x.Attribute("header").Value == "true");
```

**This code is not optimal, however to make it more efficient I would need to know more assumptions about the structure of your xml**

If you are using C#6 you could also use [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) to simplify the predicate above

```
    var elementsWithHeaders = document.Descendants("Row").Where(x => 
         x.Attribute("header")?.Value == "true");
```